# How to convert Windows FTP script to WinSCP?

Tags: ftp, winscp

I need to use WinSCP in my legacy vb6 code. I always used my script like this:

```
open ftp.myserver.com
myusername
mypassword
passive on 
cd myfolder\
ascii 
put C:\temp\test.xml test.xml
close 
quit
```

Similar script (with little change) always worked for sslftp, psftp, etc.

Now I need to create script to make this WinSCP work but it keeps throwing "host not found error". I'm not even trying the script. I'm trying it on the command window.

```
winscp> open ftp.myserver.com
Searching for host...
Network error: Connection timed out.
```

same ftp works on regular command line ftp:

```
ftp> open ftp.myserver.com
Connected to myserver.
220 Gene6 FTP Server v3.10.0
User (...): myuser
331 Password required for myuser
Password:
230 User manager logged in.
```

How do I run WinSCP? The documentation doesn't show any such example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinSCP defaults to the SFTP protocol on the port 22. If you want to use the FTP, you need to specify that explicitly.

Also username and password come in [session URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url) as part of the [`open` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open), not on separate lines. The passive mode is specified using the `-passive=on` switch.

```
open ftp://myusername:mypassword@ftp.myserver.com -passive=on
```

---

The ascii mode is specified using the `-transfer=ascii` switch of the [`put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put) (though the separate `ascii` command is also understood for compatibility):

```
put -transfer=ascii C:\temp\test.xml test.xml
```

---

It's the [`exit`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_exit), not the `quit`.

---

See the complete [guide for converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

You should also read the guide to [automating file transfers to FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).