# How to SFTP a file using batch file?

Tags: ftp, sftp, winscp, windows-task-scheduler

we need to transfer files from one server to another server via SFTP.(Job scheduler)

Currently transfer is happening via FTP. Below is the script we are using to transfer fies.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%u in ('date /t') do set d=%%v
set datestr=%d:~6,4%%d:~0,2%%d:~3,2%
rem IF %time:~0,1% GEQ 1 ( set timestr=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2% ) else ( set timestr=0%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2% )
set timestr=0%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2%
echo %datestr%_%timestr%

echo open ac8b16-a13.no.eri.us >> \\MG2PLK\INPUTPATH\Excel\Important\WDESYMPHONY.txt
echo user username password >> \\MG2PLK\INPUTPATH\Excel\Important\WDESYMPHONY.txt
echo put \\MG2PLK\OutPut\MA-Operation\Extraction\WDESymphony.txt  /dstage/dsdata/External_Input_Files/sympttkt/WDESymphony_%datestr%%timestr%.txt >> \\MG2PLK\INPUTPATH\Excel\Important\WDESYMPHONY.txt
echo put \\MG2PLK\OutPut\MA-Operation\Extraction\sympday-modified.txt  /dstage/dsdata/External_Input_Files/sympttkt/sympday-modified_%datestr%%timestr%.txt >> \\MG2PLK\INPUTPATH\Excel\Important\WDESYMPHONY.txt
echo ! copy /Y \\MG2PLK\OutPut\MA-Operation\Extraction\WDESymphony.txt \\MG2PLK\OutPut\MA-Operation\WDESymphony.txt >> \\MG2PLK\INPUTPATH\Excel\Important\WDESYMPHONY.txt
echo ! copy /Y \\MG2PLK\OutPut\MA-Operation\Extraction\sympday-modified.txt \\MG2PLK\OutPut\MA-Operation\sympday-modified.txt >> \\MG2PLK\INPUTPATH\Excel\Important\WDESYMPHONY.txt
echo close >> \\MG2PLK\INPUTPATH\Excel\Important\WDESYMPHONY.txt 
echo bye >> \\MG2PLK\INPUTPATH\Excel\Important\WDESYMPHONY.txt

Date /T >> \\MG2PLK\INPUTPATH\Excel\Important\WDESYMPHONY.log
Time /T >> \\MG2PLK\INPUTPATH\Excel\Important\WDESYMPHONY.log
C:\winnt\system32\ftp.exe -n -s:WDESYMPHONY.txt >> WDESYMPHONY.log
```

installed Winscp, and genarated public key , and share it to the another server team based on google search.
and they have added public key to the exception list .

facing trouble to generate schedule script , could you please help me how to change this FTP to SFTP for transfering files. Thank you in advance.

Tried approach:

```
echo open sftp://ftp_user:password@ftp.MyFTPSite.com -hostkey="1234" >> ftpcmd.dat
echo put c:\directory\%1-export-%date%.csv >> ftpcmd.dat
echo exit >> ftpcmd.dat
winscp.com /script=ftpcmd.dat
del ftpcmd.dat
```

tried with above approach, but facing issue with syntax. there is no password

struggling with syntax for password

Comment: Or [How to convert Windows FTP script to WinSCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20531986/850848) or [Replace Windows command FTP -s:E:\FtpScript.txt with SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21102193/850848) or [Replace FTP with SFTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25311405/850848) and many many others - This is not a code writing service - Do your research and ask a specific question with a specific problem.

Comment: *"facing issue with syntax. there is no password"* is pretty vague. There **is** a password in your script. So what's the **"issue"**?

Comment: You didn't respond to my comments to this question, yet you are asking a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48777459/850848) already.