# What is meaning of \\Server1\Folder1\Folder2\File.txt in WinSCP FTP script?

Tags: batch-file, ftp, sftp, winscp

I have a `put` command which is working in SFTP for one file.

Below, I have code using FTP and I need to convert it to SFTP:

```
echo put \\Server1\Folder1\Folder2\File1.txt  /Folder1/Folder2/sympdayedw_%datestr%%timestr%.txt >> 
\\Server1\Folder1\Folder2\File.txt
```

Can anybody explain to me what the meaning of the above syntax in FTP batch script is?
In my understanding `File1` is copied from `\\Server1\Folder1\Folder2\File1.txt`  to `/Folder1/Folder2/sympdayedw_%datestr%%timestr%.txt`, but I don't understand the meaning of `\\Server1\Folder1\Folder2\File.txt`.

Now I need to convert from FTP to SFTP, however, I am able to copy `d:\examplefile.txt` from one server to another server using SFTP using this statement:

```
D:\WINScp\winscp.com /ini=nul /command "open scp://remoteserverName:22/ -privatekey=""D:\Privatekey.ppk"" -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 18:39:f4:7b:e9:68:41:23:a3:a9:5c:0a:a8:eg:bc:1f""" "put d:\examplefile.txt"
```

Thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 0):

`\\server\share\path\file.ext` is [UNC path syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Universal_Naming_Convention).

You can use UNC path in Windows in place of a local file path to refer to a file (`path\file.ext`) in a shared folder (`share`) on another machine (`server`) of your **local** network.

It has nothing to do with FTP protocol or WinSCP.